# Javascript onClick delete query trouble

Tags: javascript, php, forms, onclick, sql-delete

It's a personal project, not going online, I don't need to worry about mysql depreciation nor SQL injections

I keep getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting
>   ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\StudentExams\examisud.php on line 64

My code in the order it's written (All in 1 php file):

My Delete query:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) //DELETE QUERY
{
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Exam WHERE exam_id='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
};
```

My form:

```
echo "<form action=examisud.php method=post>"; //HTML FORM ECHOED OUT BY PHP
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=exam_id value=" . $record['exam_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=subject value=" . $record['subject'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=exam_date value=" . $record['exam_date'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['exam_id'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=image name=update value=update id=submit src=images/update.png" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=image name=delete value=delete id=submit onClick="return deleteconfig()" src=images/delete.png" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<form action=examisud.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uexam_id></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=usubject></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uexam_date></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=image name=insert value=insert id=submit src=images/insert.png" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
echo '</div>';
```

My javascript:

```
<html>
<header>
<script>
function deleteconfig(){

var del=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
if (del==true){
   alert ("record deleted")
}else{
    alert("Record Not Deleted")
}
return del;
}
</script>
</header>
</html>
```

How can I get this code to work right? I need a pop up asking me to confirm if I want to delete the field values or not. I'm quite a newbie at php AND javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt escaped quotes in your echo.. :

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=image name=delete value=delete id=submit onClick=\"return deleteconfig()\" src=images/delete.png" . " </td>";
```

Comment: Wow...such a n00b mistake. I had seperators in earlier, but I had the first \ INSIDE of the quotes -_- Thanks for showing me my idiocy!

Comment: I tried, but it said I had to wait 5 mins before I could ahaha!

Answer (score 0):

Just a cosmetic tip: Instead of a `echo` on each line, you could just concatenate the whole string with `.`, and still use line breaks for each line.

Also, it appears you've forgotten to close a couple of the `input` elements.

I would also recommend using quotes in the html's properties. On short properties like `type=text`, it's not mandatory, but longer values like an `src` really can't do without.

Last, try to use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`), and avoid string concatenation where it isn't necessary (combining 2 static strings), like this:

```
echo '<form action="examisud.php" method="post">'. //HTML FORM ECHOED OUT BY PHP
        '<tr>'.
            '<td><input type="text" name="exam_id" value="' . $record['exam_id'] . '" </td>'.
            '<td><input type="text" name="subject" value="' . $record['subject'] . '" </td>'.
            '<td><input type="text" name="exam_date" value="' . $record['exam_date'] . '" </td>'.
            '<td><input type="hidden" name=hidden" value="' . $record['exam_id'] . '" </td>'.
            '<td><input type="image" name="update" value="update" id="submit" src="images/update.png" ></td>'.
            '<td><input type="image" name="delete" value="delete" id="submit" onClick="return deleteconfig()" src="images/delete.png" ></td>'.
        '</tr>'.
    '</form>';
}
echo '<form action="examisud.php" method="post">'.
        '<tr>'.
            '<td><input type="text" name="uexam_id"></td>'.
            '<td><input type="text" name="usubject"></td>'.
            '<td><input type="text" name="uexam_date"></td>'.
            '<td><input type="image name="insert" value="insert" id="submit" src="images/insert.png" ></td>'.
        '</tr>'.
    '</form>'.
'</table>'.
'</div>';
```

Using single quotes tells the php interpreter not to bother checking for variables in the strings. This, and the reduced amount of concatenation make for more efficient, and in my opinion, more readable code.

As for your JavaScript:

```
if (del==true){
```

Can be replaced with

```
if (del){
```

An `if` checks whether it's value is true(-ish) or not. Since `confirm` returns a boolean output, there's no need to check if `true == true` or `false == true`.

Comment: Thanks Cerbrus, I will defo take those suggestions on board!